# How can ping resolve an address but other programs can't?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-14.04

I get this:

```
$ ping outlook.office365.com
PING outlook-namwest.office365.com (132.245.24.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 132.245.24.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=242 time=17.6 ms

$ wget http://outlook.office365.com
--2016-04-20 17:27:33--  http://outlook.office365.com/
Resolving outlook.office365.com (outlook.office365.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘outlook.office365.com’
```

Note that wget says "unable to resolve" not "can't connect".

It is *only* for that host.  Any other website works.

`wget http://132.245.24.2` also works.

Loading `http://outlook.office365.com` in Firefox also fails.

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Platform: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, x86-64.  No recent config changes or software updates that I am aware of.  This stopped working today (was ok yesterday).

Comment: What does the `hosts:` line in your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` look like?

Comment: @84104: I have `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns`.  File mod date a year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with IPv6.
If the result of `host -t aaaa outlook.office365.com` is "failed: connection refused.", please try `wget -4 http://outlook.office365.com/`.

Comment: Spot on!  That works.  Now: how do I disable IPv6 temporarily on my system?

Comment: Also, why does the resolve fail for IPv6 only?  I can see how connectivity may fail in a v6 only way, but not necessarily how resolve would fail in a v6 only way.

Comment: I think, your DNS Server does not support IPv6.
`host -t aaaa outlook.office365.com 8.8.8.8` (Query to Google's DNS Server) => correct result.